# What would be the better usage of return in try catch block?

Tags: java, return

So below is my code

```
private String downloadContents (String urlPath){
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            URL url = new URL (urlPath);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int response = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("DownloadData", "Response code was " + response);
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numChar;
            char[] readBuffer = new char [500];

            while (true){
                numChar = isr.read(readBuffer);
                if (numChar <= 0){
                    break;
                }
                stringBuffer.append(readBuffer);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

I am wondering if putting `return stringBuffer.toString();` just before the end of try block and returning empty stringBuffer at the end is better or if `return stringBuffer.toString();` at the end of the whole method would be better.

I'm thinking even if I put `stringBuffer.toString();` at the end of the whole method, it would probably still return null if some error had occurred before `stringBuffer` was constructed in case of my simple code. Will there be any advantages or disadvantages of the two positions? What is the most "orthodox" method of returning try catch block?

Comment: As is, if an error is thrown in the block, the method will return an empty string, not `null`

Comment: Your method won't return `null` as nothing can go wrong before you construct the `StringBuffer`.  In the event of an error you're going to return an empty string though, is that really what you want to do?

Comment: ah yes that's my bad I didn't mean to say null but to say empty

Comment: So in case of this code, what would be the best return for after catch? so it's downloading an xml content but if an error occurs, catch block will print error anyway so I would still be notified that error occurs, meaning I don't really have to return a value corresponding to the error? @MrWiggles

Comment: Maybe you should throw an exception when your method can't do what it was supposed to do.

Comment: isn't throwing the same as catching except that when I throw I have to catch exception myself but computer ignores it for me if I catch exception? correct me please as I am probably wrong.. Still newbie @khelwood

Comment: Throwing an exception from a method indicates that it did not run successfully, and whoever calls the method should catch the exception and decide how to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, nothing would be affected as StringBuffer is created before try/catch block. So last statement will return either empty string or data received from URL.

But, suppose if we modify the statements as:

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;
try {
    stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    //...
}catch(Exception e){
    //...
}
return stringBuffer.toString();
```

In this case, return statement cannot be put in the last as it is prone to `NullPointerException`. So, there will be two different return statements for try and catch blocks.

There is no such orthodox for using return in try/catch blocks. It totally depends on your algorithm. In some cases, you might need to return from the try blocks as well. Suppose your API returns `int` as error code, so it might be possible that different error codes are required for different conditions within a try block.

In this scenario, you cannot return a variable (say `int errorCode` that stores error values for different conditions) in the last because you will need to break the code at error. In Java, `break` won't work on `try` block so `return` statement must be used within `try`.

Comment: Ah great thanks. So generally unless I need various return conditions within try block or if my variable had already been stored as null, it wont matter too much.

Comment: Yes.
It could be single return statement as well, If return statement is not the last statement of try block due to some reason.